# Git flow command error: 'flow' is not a git command

Tags: github, git-svn, git-branch, git-flow

I am very new to Git and am starting to learn the command line version. I believe my git flow is not installed correctly. I am running this from a pc.

When i run following command:

```
git flow feature start JamesTest
```

I get the following error:

> git: 'flow' is not a git command. See 'git --help'
>   Did you mean any of these?

Looks like the git flow command is not being recognized from all paths? How do I fix this?

Comment: `flow` is not a native Git command. It's more like a Git plugin or extension. What operating system are you on?

Comment: Hi Chris - I am running on Win 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Unfortunately, installing on Windows [is somewhat involved](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Windows). If you installed Git from http://git-scm.com/ you should follow the MSysGit instructions.

Answer (score 48):

The git flow is not installed in your machine. Just run this command,

macOS:

```
$ brew install git-flow-avh
```

Linux:

```
$ apt-get install git-flow
```

Windows:

```
$ wget -q -O - --no-check-certificate https://raw.github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/develop/contrib/gitflow-installer.sh install stable | bash
```

> Source [git-flow cheatsheet by Daniel Kummer](https://danielkummer.github.io/git-flow-cheatsheet/)

After successful installation run `git flow init` in your project and then follow the instructions to configure the git flow.

Comment: Any difference between `brew install git-flow-avh` and `brew install git-flow`?

Answer (score 23):

Git is installed but Gitflow is not. Gitflow is a Git extension and has to be installed separately.

Install it as [described on GitHub](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Installation) and you should be fine ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to install Git Flow on Windows, do as follows (based on [this instructions](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh/wiki/Installing-on-Windows))

1. Clone the git flow repository

   ```
   git clone --recursive git://github.com/nvie/gitflow.git
   ```
2. Download the [`getopt`](https://s3.amazonaws.com/gitflow-avh-edition/gitflow-getopt-windows.zip) archive and extract the `getopt.exe` file to the location where Git executable is installed (something like C:\Programs\Git\bin)
3. Execute the following command, where the argument is the Git path installation (again, something like C:\Programs\Git). You don't need to specify the `bin` directory here.

   ```
   contrib\msysgit-install.cmd "C:\Programs\Git"
   ```

And that's it. Check that all is working using the command `git flow`

Comment: Thanks, this is a much simpler set of instructions than the instructions in Lubos other answer :)

Answer (score 1):

For mac users, just make sure **git-flow** is installed. If it is not installed, run these commands respectively:

1. `/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
2. `brew install git-flow`
3. `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`
4. `git flow init`

Sometimes even **git-flow** is installed, it doesn't work, all what you need is to export `brew` before using `git flow`:

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```